# uiWebView printing a pdf

Tags: pdf, iframe, printing, uiwebview

Inside of uiwebview, what is a good way print a pdf document?

The pdf is accessible via a url or it can be loaded inside of an iframe.

Using the standard javascript widnow.print() functions will not work.

I am considering using a javascript bridge such as:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *URL = [request URL]; 

    if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"native"]) { 
        NSString *urlString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
        NSArray *urlParts = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        NSString *cmd = [urlParts objectAtIndex:1];

        if ( [cmd isEqualToString:@"printPdf"] ) {
            //  [self dosomething];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

At this point I need some sort of xcode function which accept a path to the pdf and send it the airPrinter.

Is this a good approach?  I am searching examples of how to print a pdf inside a uiWebView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've earned the tumbleweed badge for no up votes and no responses, I'll post my solution.

This fetches the pdf doc and opens the airPrint dialog--all within a uiWebView.

So if IOS would simply allow the javascript window.print() to function inside of uiWebView, my app would not be setting in the app store waiting for approval and re-release.

Anyway, here's a working solution:

```
- (void)printInit:(NSString *)parm  {

    UIPrintInteractionController *controller = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    if(!controller){
        NSLog(@"Couldn't get shared UIPrintInteractionController!");
        return;
    }

    NSString *base = @"https://someurl.com/";
    NSString *ustr = [base stringByAppendingString:parm];

    //NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:ustr];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:ustr];    
    NSData *thePdf = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    controller.printingItem = thePdf;
    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = @"PDFDoc";
    controller.printInfo = printInfo;

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed && error) {
             NSLog(@"FAILED! error = %@",[error localizedDescription]);
        }
    };

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(310, 5, 100, 5);
    [controller presentFromRect:rect inView:self.webView animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```